# How to chance a video src by clicking links that contain other video src [Java Script]

Tags: javascript, video, click, switch-statement, src

I need to switch the #cat video src whith the .cover src I clicked

```html
<video width="100%" height="100%" id="cat">
    <source src="es.mp4"  id='Source' type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  
  
  <video class="cover">
    <source src="Wes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video class="cover">
    <source src="For_Wes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

I tried to do make it with something like that :

```html
var a = document.getElementById('Source');
    var b = a.getAttribute('href');
    document.getElementsByClassName("cover").onclick{
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array to loop through (Be sure to keep HTML structure the same if you add more videos). Then add listener to each cover. When cover is clicked, update the main video source.

```js
(function(video, covers) {
  /** create loopable array */
  covers = Array.prototype.slice.call(covers);

  function update(target, source) {
    /** update the source attribute */
    source.setAttribute('src', target.getAttribute('src'));
  }

  function onClick(cover) {
    /** Add Listener to each cover */
    cover.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      /** call update on each click */
      update(event.target.firstElementChild, video);
    }, false);
  }

  covers.forEach(onClick);
}(document.querySelector('#Source'), document.querySelectorAll('.cover')));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>How to chance a video src by clicking links that contain other video src [Java Script]</title>
</head>

<body>

  <video width="100%" height="100%" id="cat">
    <source src="es.mp4" id='Source' type="video/mp4">
  </video>


  <video class="cover">
    <source src="Wes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video class="cover">
    <source src="For_Wes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

</body>

</html>
```